# AppDomain.AssemblyResolve doesn't work (as expected) with MEF

Tags: c#, .net, mef, .net-assembly

I have this error:

```
Runtime error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'StiOracleSource' does not exist in the namespace 'Stimulsoft.Report.Dictionary'
```

I developed (VS 2012) an application that uses MEF (.NET 4.5) to interconnect several binary assemblies loaded from a database. One of its separate plug-in assemblies (implemented as an stand-alone executable) has dependency on a third party DLL (Database adapter) that cannot be included in the main application. When I run the plug-in as a stand-alone application everything goes fine but if I load that assembly as a MEF part into the main application then I got CS0234 error runtime despite I provide the third party DLL reference using **AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve** event approach. Referencing the third party DLL in the main application doesn't help.

Can anyone explain why the plug-in assembly runs smoothly as a stand-alone application and why it is broken when it is executed as a part of the MEF?

Comment: More often than not.. I've found that this is a .NET version mis-match. Verify they are both compiled against the same .NET version (4.5).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but the plug-in and the main application are both built against the same .NET version 4.5. Even the database adapter is built against 4.5. But the visual components of the third party components are all built against the 2.0 version. Anyway, I don't think it's the case because the stand-alone application runs OK despite that difference in .NET versions.